# Numpy para qué sirve el -1 en reshape()

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy

Me encuentro haciendo cambios de matrices con `Numpy`:

```
array = np.array([[1,2],
                  [4,5],
                  [6,7],
                  [8,9]])
```

Estoy con utilizando `reshape()` y lo entiendo perfectamente lo que hace  cambiar la forma de la matriz.

Lo que no entiendo que hace el `-1` porque no elimina filas o columnas luego ¿Qué hace? Tampoco crea ninguna dimensión.

Tras muchas pruebas y leer la documentación no entiendo su funcionamiento.

¿Alguien me lo puede explicar por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hace `reshape(-1)` es mantener esa **dimensión de tamaño indefinido** y hacer que se ajuste al resto de las dimensiones, por eso `numpy` **solo te lo permite hacer una única vez**, ya que si tubiera dos dimensiones con el tamaño sin definir, **sería imposible averiguar como quieres formar el array.** Siguiendo con tu ejemplo

```
array_2d = np.array([[1,2],
                  [4,5],
                  [6,7],
                  [8,9]])

array_2d.reshape(-1, 4)
```

**Salida:**

```
array([[1, 2, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Aquí le hemos indicado, quiero que el array tenga 4 columnas, y para ello ajusta las filas como tu desees, claramente si tienes ocho elementos en total y le obligas a tener cuatro columnas, el -1 realmente son 2 filas, es decir una matriz (2,4).

Aquí otro ejemplo donde indico que haya ocho filas y el número de columnas se ajuste para que queden una columna, por lo que queda una matriz (8,1):

```
array_2d.reshape(8, -1)
```

**Salida:**

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

**Incluso podemos seguir añadiendo dimensiones**, por ejemplo aquí le indico que me cree varias matrices (2,2) de tal forma que nos encontramos en tres dimensiones, y el número de matrices en tres dimensiones que creará se lo dejaré indefinido a `Numpy` mediante `-1`

```
array_2d.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
```

**Salida:**

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5]],

       [[6, 7],
        [8, 9]]])
```

El -1 en este caso se transforma en un dos, ya que una matriz (2,4), se puede expresar tambien como (2,2,2).

## Nota

Claramente no puede hacer transformaciones matemáticas imposibles, como tranformar nuestra matriz inicial (4,2) en una matriz (10,2), ya que no tenemos 20 elementos. Siempre debe ser matematicamente posible la transformación, en caso contrario nos dará el error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size N into shape (x,y)`